# selectable checkbox in gridview

Tags: .net, datagridviewcheckboxcell

VS2010 .net

I have a gridview that displays information from a database.  One of the fields is a checkbox.  What I would like to do is be able to click the checkbox and have it update back to the database, but the checkbox field is grayed-out.  Below is my markup.   searching for making checkboxes clickable does not return any helpful results.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvSiteInfo" runat="server" BackColor="White" 
    GridLines="Vertical" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnSorting="gvSiteInfo_Sorting" 
    onselectedindexchanged="gvSiteInfo_SelectedIndexChanged" 
    AllowSorting="True">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="prodServer" HeaderText="Production Server" 
            SortExpression="prodServer" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="prodHostHeader" HeaderText="Production Host Header" 
            SortExpression="prodHostHeader" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="prodIP" HeaderText="Production IP Address" 
            SortExpression="prodIP" />
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="testComplete" HeaderText="Testing Completed" 
            SortExpression="testComplete" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `templatefield`:

```
                       <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelector" runat="server"
                                    ToolTip="Select row?" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
```

You also do not seem to set the value based on the database:

```
Checked='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.IsChecked") %>'
```

Comment: When i use `<asp:CheckBox ID="cbTestComplete" runat="server" Checked='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.testComplete") %>' />`   I get an "InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code" error.  However, the database is returning either 'true' or 'false' so i don't understand why there is an error.

Comment: problem solved.   the 'checked' was looking for a boolean, and i thought passing it 'true' or 'false' would satisfy this.  but what i had to do was `Checked='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.testComplete").toString().Equals("true")`

Comment: @Mike great job, yes if you are storing them in the db as "true" or "false".